# Make element locator unique

Tags: selenium, element

I am a beginner Selenium learner practicing Automation using Eclipse, and I am working on automating a test case with the following first two steps:

```
Go to http://automationpractice.com/index.php
Verify -5% displayed on product 'Printed Summer Dress'
```

For the second step I have the following problem:
I cannot create a unique locator for the -5% element on the web page. I tried different element locators, but in the 'Inspect' elements console, in the 'Find by string, selector, or Xpath' search bar, the locators bring multiple results, such as 1 of 8 or 1 of 4. I definitely want to ensure I use a unique element locator, so that when I run the test, I get full-proof result.

This is the element:

```
<span class="price-percent-reduction">-5%</span>
```

As far as I can tell, there are no other element attributes, other than class so I cannot use an alternative attribute.

Note: This is neither homework nor classwork, but my own practice.

I tried using the following locators, but none of them get 1 of 1 result, meaning they are not unique.

```
CSS --> span.price-percent-reduction
CSS --> span[class='price-percent-reduction']
XPath --> //span[text()='-5%']
XPath --> //span[@class='price-percent-reduction']
```

I searched for similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but could not find one matching my own.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with your assumption that locating `<span class="price-percent-reduction">` will return multiple elements. It looks like you are trying to locate a specific product on a page, with a price-percent reduction. So you will need to locate the `span` in the context of the product you are looking for.

Here's an expanded XPath that looks at the product title and fetches the percentage discount based on that:

```
//ul[@id='homefeatured']//div[h5/a[@title='Printed Chiffon Dress']]/div/span[@class='price-percent-reduction']
```

This selector returns 1 result of `-20%`, which is the percentage discount on product `Printed Chiffon Dress`.

This can be generalized to:

```
//ul[@id='homefeatured']//div[h5/a[@title='product title here']]/div/span[@class='price-percent-reduction']
```

The XPath can be broken down as follows:

The website has two product lists -- 'Popular' and 'Best sellers' These two product lists have duplicate products -- some 'Popular' products are also on the best sellers list. In order to retrieve a single product element, we need to specify the list. The XPath above specifies the 'Popular' list, indicated by the `//ul[@id='homefeatured']` clause. Note that this can be changed to `//ul[@id='blockbestsellers']` to choose from 'Best Sellers' list instead.

After we select on `//ul[@id='homefeatured']`, we query on product within the list, using the `title` attribute which appears inside the clause `//div[h5/a[@title='product title here']]`. This query tells our path to search for the containing `div` element that contains the title `product title here`.

Once we select the product based on its title, we can query down to the price percentage reduction, the `/div/span[@class='price-percent-reduction']` portion of the clause.

With the resulting XPath, you can change `product title here` to `Printed Chiffon Dress` or the title of any other project, and get the %off (-5%) value that appears under that product.

It's worth noting - I use an XPath helper extension for my Google Chrome, so I can test most XPaths in real-time, and I can write complicated evaluations such as the path I wrote above. This is the mechanism I was using to test this XPath against the website URL you provided.

Answer (score 0):

To get the unique element of reduction `-5%` use following xpath.

```
//ul[@id='homefeatured'][.//a[@title='Printed Summer Dress']]//div[@class='right-block']//span[@class='price-percent-reduction'][text()='-5%']
```

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibilityOfElementLocated`()

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
WebElement itempricediscount=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@id='homefeatured'][.//a[@title='Printed Summer Dress']]//div[@class='right-block']//span[@class='price-percent-reduction'][text()='-5%']")));
System.out.println(itempricediscount.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a css for that:

```
#homefeatured > li:nth-child(5) .left-block .price-percent-reduction
```

What I do is search for it in chrome elements panel and keep going up until something's unique